# Laravel 5 - where to place reusable custom validator?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, code-organization, laravel-validation

I'm wondering where is the correct place for custom validator which I want to use on more then one place?

For example, I have `min_image_size` validator:

```
Validator::extend('min_image_size', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    $imageSize = getimagesize($value->getPathname());
    return ($imageSize[0] >= $parameters[0] && $imageSize[1] >= $parameters[1]);
});
```

Where should I place it according right Laravel-way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely extend the validator in a [Service Provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers). You can use the existing `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` or create another one just for validation.

Then, in the `boot()` method, add this:

```
public function boot(){
    $this->app['validator']->extend('min_image_size', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        $imageSize = getimagesize($value->getPathname());
        return ($imageSize[0] >= $parameters[0] && $imageSize[1] >= $parameters[1]);
    });
}
```

It might also be worth putting the actual validation rules in a separate class and using this syntax:

```
$this->app['validator']->extend('min_image_size', 'MyCustomValidator@validateMinImageSize');
```

Answer (score -2):

I think I will create a class for custom validation where I can write my custom rules and will put it into libraries folder or may be middleware.